# makefile trouble C++ - No rule to make target

Tags: c++, makefile

So I am having quite a bit of trouble trying to get a makefile to work with my project. As it stands I am getting an error that states

make: *** No rule to make target `../obj/Game.o', needed by`jamoo'.  Stop.
my file system is set up like this

```
makefile
/src
    .cpp files
/include
    .h files
/obj
```

and here is the makefile.

```
# MODULES are the names of files without extensions to be compiled
MODULES = Game Map Door_Node Floor_Tile Room_Node
#SOURCES are the .cpp files
SOURCES = $(addsuffix .cpp, $(MODULES))
#DEPS are the .hpp files we are compiling against
DEPS = $(SOURCES: .cpp=.hpp)
# OBJS are the .o files that we compile to before linking
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
# CC is the compiler
CC = g++
# Compiler Options
CFLAGS = -o jamoo -I -Werror -Wall

# Library Linking Options
LFLAGS =

../obj/%.o: ../src/%.cpp ../include/%.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)

jamoo: $(patsubst %, ../obj/%.o, $(MODULES))
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)

clean:
    rm jamoo
```

I think the issue is that make is unable to resolve the file system, but I don't know how to write the makefile to do so. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You don't need all of these custom rules. Setting `$vpath` should let make sort out, where to find the prerequisites.

Comment: The `-o jamoo` in CFLAGS is going to make every compile output to a file named `jamoo`...  Probably not what you want.  Look at a basic makefile tutorial like [this](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/).

Comment: Which directory are you in, when you execute Make? I suspect you're in the project root directory (the one containing the makefile), in which case there is no "../src/" directory; there's a directory "src/", but that's not where you told Make to look.